# Is a many to many relationship bad? What about this example?

Tags: database-design

According to "Database Processing: Fundamentals, Design, and Implementation"  11th ed.,

> "The problem for the data models of N:M relationships between strong
>   entity is that they have no direct representation.  An N:M
>   relationship must always be decomposed into two 1:N relationships
>   using an intersection table in the database design."

OK, I get that.  But what if your intersection table creates a many to many.  I have come up with a simple example.  Lets take a video store.  The video store has many copies of each movie, and each movie has many actors.  So, to show the database tables:

```
TITLE  (The movie title.)
TitleNumber   (unique pk)
Title

VIDEO 
VideoNumber   (each copy is unique even across titles, so unique  pk)
TitleNumber  (fk)

TITLE_ACTOR
TitleNumber  (pk)
ActorNumber  (pk)
CharactorPlayed

ACTOR
ActorNumber  (pk)
FirstName
LastName
```

So lets say you have three copies of Star Wars I.  And a copy of Raiders of the lost arc.  Star wars would have video numbers 1-3 and Raiders would have video number 4, and the next movie or copy would be 5.

So the issue I see is that `VIDEO` and `TITLE_ACTOR` both have the `TitleNumber` (I.e. movie title) in common.  And both tables allow for many duplicates of the `TitleNumber`, many copies of a title and a title can have many actors.  So `VIDEO` to `TITLE_ACTOR` is a many to many relationship.  Is that correct so far?  Or does the composite key change it?  Or something else?

Normally you join these with a transition table, but they are already joined.  I don't see a way to move a attribute over to make a 1:M without anomolies.

I have spent many days researching this, books and online.  Please be kind as I am here to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationships can be diagrammed as follows:

```
VIDEO >-- TITLE --< TITLE_ACTOR >-- ACTOR
```

Where "`>--`" is a many-to-one relationship and "`--<`" is one-to-many.

You're right that a query that joins VIDEO to TITLE_ACTOR, even indirectly via TITLE, is going to match N rows from VIDEO to M rows from TITLE_ACTOR, and the result set will have N*M rows for a given TITLE.  That's a Cartesian product between VIDEO and TITLE_ACTOR, if there are no direct join restrictions between those two tables.

---

Re your comments:

The diagram notation I show can illustrate the difference between a *logical* many-to-many relationship, and the *physical* implementation of that relationship, using an intersection table containing two many-to-one relationships.  For example, the logical relationship we're trying to represent is the following:

```
       TITLE >---< ACTOR
```

You might draw your logical data model this way while you're designing the relationships.

But SQL does not support a way to store a many-to-many relationship.  To store it physically in the database, we must use an intersection table:

```
TITLE --< TITLE_ACTOR >-- ACTOR
```

For any logical many-to-many relationship, your physical model adds an intersection table and reverses the direction of the arrows.  This physical model achieves the same relationship as the logical many-to-many relationship.

> Does this mean that on a diagram, that I shouldn't show a direct relationship from video to title_actor?

Yes, I would consider there to be the following relationships:

- VIDEO references TITLE (M:1)
- TITLE_ACTOR references TITLE (M:1)
- TITLE_ACTOR references ACTOR (M:1)

But there is *no* direct relationship from VIDEO to TITLE_ACTOR.  Only an indirect relationship via TITLE.

The references correspond to foreign key constraints.  For example, VIDEO contains a foreign key referencing TITLE, but VIDEO *does not* contain (and has no need for) a foreign key referencing TITLE_ACTOR.

FWIW, the diagram above is my attempt to make a simple ASCII format of an [Entity-Relationship Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model).

Comment: I like your diagram, with the<>, very creative.  Yes, I agree with your relationship diagram.  Looked up Cartesian, basically a cross join.  OK.  So... Does this mean that on a diagram, that I shouldn't show a direct relationship from video to title_actor?  If so, then this is making sense.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it now.  Nice clear answer, and fast, great job.  I have used software for two years, first time I have had to post.  SOF is the best Q&A forum.  Also thanks to Robert and paulsm4.  Sorry can't vote up, but did the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Is a many to many relationship bad?

A: No, of course not!

> Lets take a video store. The video store has many copies of each
>   movie, and each movie has many actors. So, to show the database
>   tables:
>
> TITLE (The movie title.) TitleNumber (unique pk) Title
>
> VIDEO VideoNumber (each copy is unique even across titles, so unique
>   pk) TitleNumber (fk)
>
> TITLE_ACTOR TitleNumber (pk) ActorNumber (pk) CharactorPlayed
>
> ACTOR ActorNumber (pk) FirstName LastName

For a video store, I might have just ONE table: "video_selections":

```
create table video_selections (
  title varchar(20) not null,  -- EX: Star Wars
  serial_no varchar(20) not null,
  type char(1) not null, -- V)HS, D)VD, B)lu-Ray
  genre char(1) not null,
  star varchar(20) not null,
  director varchar(20) not null,
  release_date datetime not null
  checkout_date datetime,
  return_date datetime
)
```

This could easily a) keep track of inventory, b) allow searches based on title, genre or star and c) cross-reference actor (at least lead actor) and movie title or movie genre.

On the other hand, if you were creating a movie database, you might want the following tables:

```
table movie
  title
  release_date
  ...

table actors
  name
  birthdate
  biographical info
  ...

table roles
  movie_title
  actor_name
  ...
```

Table "roles", of course, would model the many-to-many relationship between movies (which have multiple actors) and actors (who may appear in multiple films).

'Hope that helps ... at least a little bit...

Comment: The issue I see with one table is insertion anomolies.  I.e. Harrison Ford might be spelled many different ways.  With the movie database suggestion, that seems to be basically what I have?  If so, does that mean what I have is OK?  I am trying to get things normalized to 3NF or BCNF.  Normalizing is new to me but not database design.

Comment: @paulsm4: It should be made clear that your one-table design is a denormalized design, a sort of [Star Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).  It doesn't prevent anomalies, but it can represent searchable "facts" about your movie collection, to support a subset of report types efficiently.